# How do you loop through a string in php and replace '%' characters that are ONLY followed by another '%' character?

Tags: php, regex, url, loops

Here is what I am trying to achieve in PHP:

I have this string: host/%%%25asd%%

Now I want to loop through it and replace only the % _blank characters with %25. So I get the output as host/%25%25%25asd%25%25. (The %25 was untouched because the % wasn't followed by another %)

How should I go by doing this? regex? if so do you have an example? or loop through every character in the string and replace? I was thinking about using str_pos for this but it might after one replacement, the positions in the string would change :(

[Edit: Let me add a couple more information to ease up the confusion. %25 is just an example, it could be anything like %30 or %0a, I won't know before hand. Also the string could also be host/%%25asd%% so a simple replace for %% screw it up as host/%2525asd%25 instead of host/%25%25asd%25. What am trying to achieve is to parse a url into how google wants it for their websafe api. http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/developers_guide_v2.html#Canonicalization. If you look at their weird examples.]

Comment: Although something like `s/%(?![0-9a-f]+)/%25/ig;` will cure the % escaping, you have a long way to go to construct methods that will validate a canonicalization implementation that is in that google api link.

Comment: I now understand that sin, the examples get horrible from one to the other. Most of the time you need to go recursive! Eitherways I will work it out and maybe release a php class under GPL license, so the next person doesn't have to scratch his head for 2 days over it.

Eg:- http://host/%2525252525252525 => http://host/%25
      (The %25="%" which joins the next "25" to become another %25 and on and on recursively)

Take Care and Thank you for your feedback!!

Comment: no problem and good luck. `s/%(?:25){2,}/%25/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = preg_replace('/%(?=%)/', '%25', $string);
```

Note the lookahead assertion. This matches every `%` that is followed by a `%` and replaces it with `%25`.

Result is:

```
host/%25%25%25asd%25%
```

*EDIT* Missed the case for the last `%`, see:

```
$string = preg_replace('/%(?=(%|$))/', '%25', $string);
```

So the lookahead assertion checks the next character for another `%` *or* the end of the line.

Comment: Thank Hamish for the reply. From the regex, it looked like it would work beautifully, but it skips the 25. The output should have been host/%25%25%25asd%25%25

Answer (score 3):

How about a [simple string](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-str_replace.php) (non-regex) replace of '%%' by '%25%25'?

This is assuming you indeed want the output to be host/%25%25%25asd%25%25 as you mentioned and not **one** %25 at the end.

*edit*: This is another method that might work in your case:

Use the methods [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), e.g.:

```
$string = urlencode(urldecode("host/%%%25asd%%"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I thought of it, but the problem with that is if I want to convert a such as "host/%%25asd%%" then it will mess it up into host/%25%2525asd%25%25 and not host/%25%25asd%25%25. Get it?

Comment: If you want to account for all possible combinations preg_replace with lookaheads is the way to go, plus doing a training % by hand. Or see the other method I added above.

Comment: I tried to use it but then I realized from google's examples that sometimes I go recursive/nested, so using urldecode wouldn't make sense. But thank you for taking time in trying to find me a solution. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace[enter link description here](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead of preg_replace , its a lot easier to apply and clean

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

`s/%(?![0-9a-f]+)/%25/ig;`

```
$str = 'host/%%%25asd%%';
$str =~ s/ % (?![0-9a-f]+) /%25/xig;
print $str."\n";
```

`host/%25%25%25asd%25%25`